# Is there a way to download the whole earth satellite image and terrain for Cesium use?

Tags: cesium

**Background:**

I'm developing some things based on Cesium lib offline(without the internet). So I have to set up a local tile/TMS server for use in offline network conditions. I need some guidance/information about how to search/download all Earth satellite images and terrain.

**Question:**

Is there a way/link to download the **whole Earth satellite image and terrain** for Cesium use?

**Note:**

Anything related will be welcome, a specific, and personally proven way will be more welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can try here and even produce your custom terrain.

You can preview and download server software for free aswell

https://portal.terrainserver.com

Note: I am the provider for that service